# keeping DRY while using JSData and Sequelize

Tags: dry, sequelize.js, jsdata

Does JSData replace or complement Sequelize.js?

I am trying to understand how those two libraries can play together and if they should.

From my reading it looks like JSData mainly deals with accessing data while Sequelize.js will create and modify the scema and ALSO provide access to the objects.

Is there any point in using JSData on the server side if I use Sequelize.js?

I am thinking to use Sequelize on the server side, implement some REST API to those objects and use JSData + JSDATA-http on the client side to access the REST API, but it feels that I will have to define the objects twice... once for Sequelize and once for JSData - is there any magic that can prevent the need to do this twice? or am I thinking about all this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 2):

> Does JSData replace or complement Sequelize.js? I am trying to understand how those two libraries can play together and if they should.

On the server, js-data + js-data-sql would replace Sequelize, similar to how js-data + js-data-mongodb would replace Mongoose. js-data-sql uses Knex.js under the hood, which you can use for schema migrations and for anything else that Knex supports. For schema validation, you can plug your favorite validation library into js-data via the `validate` lifecycle hook (and other places).

> Is there any point in using JSData on the server side if I use Sequelize.js?

No

> I am thinking to use Sequelize on the server side, implement some REST API to those objects and use JSData + JSDATA-http on the client side to access the REST API, but it feels that I will have to define the objects twice...once for Sequelize and once for JSData - is there any magic that can prevent the need to do this twice?

I actually have experience using js-data + js-data-http on the client and Sequelize on the server. You could do that, but yes, you have have to define each of your Models/Resources twice, once using the Sequelize API and once using the js-data API. You can mitigate duplication by extracting common logic into "base" models than can be used by the server and the client. Though, if you use js-data on the server, you can compose complex queries right in the client, without having to translate them to something the server's ORM understands.

> or am I thinking about all this in the wrong way?

No, you're just trying to understand your options. Being the author of js-data, I would of course argue in favor of js-data + js-data-sql, but the major areas where js-data + js-data-sql lags behind Sequelize is that Sequelize has native support for belongsToMany (n:m) relationships and a built-in understanding of sql datatypes (validation is up to you with js-data).

Comment: Thanks For your response, and thanks for writing this tool.
I would like to point that going through the documentation it did not "pop out" that js-data actually manages stuff like creating tables and so on. Could you point me towards an example showing how this works? and when in the codes life cycle does it happen? also if you could elaborate on the "sql datatypes" issue it could  be helpful. As for n:m one can probably use n:1 + 1:m relations to overcome this....

Comment: js-data does not automatically create tables. Creating tables only even makes sense when you're using the sql adapter. Mongo automatically creates collections for you, and the other adapters have no notion of tables. Example of creating tables with the sql adapter: https://github.com/js-data/js-data-examples/blob/master/server/sql/app/app.js#L197 It happens only where you make it happen.

n:1 + 1:m is how n:m works, it's just Sequelize understands this and hides the intermediate table. With js-data you'd have to deal with the intermediate table.

Comment: thanks, so it looks like I will revert back to the idea of using sequelize on the server side and js-data on the client side...